# Как измерить расстояние от точки А до точки Б на карте по их координатам?

Tags: python, api, карты, яндекс-карты, координаты

Есть 2 точки
А и Б они имеют координаты А = 53.902284, 27.561831 и Б = 55.755864, 37.617698.
Мне нужно получить расстояние от точки А до точки Б. Как это можно сделать ?
Гуглил апишки Яндекс карт и гугл мапс, но там ничего дельного не нашёл. Подскажите хотя бы в  каком направлении думать.

В идеале построить маршрут с помощью любого геокодера, который позволит это сделать

Comment: И всё же: нужно просто расстояние по прямой (ну хорошо - по дуге) или маршрут? Это разное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через [апи яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/router/doc/concepts/quickstart.html) и requsets.

```
import requests

coord1='' 
coord2='' 

params={
    'waypoints':coord1+'|'+coord2, 
    'apikey':'ключ' 
} 

response=requests.get(  
    'https://api.routing.yandex.net/v2/route',
    params=params
).json

length=response['route']['legs'][0]['steps'] 
length=[i['length'] for i in length] 
length=sum(length) #длина маршрута
```